# Can't import a file from a python package

Tags: python, import, package

Here is the structure of my application:

```
 app
   +---__init__.py
   +--- util.py
 myscripts
     run.py
     model
        +---- __init__.py
        +---- model.py
     base
       +---- __init__.py
       +---- common.py
```

in the file run, i have this:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../app/'))
from app import util
```

But I get this error:

```
    from app import util
ImportError: No module named app
```

I tried all the solutions I could find, but none works for me. Any ideas please?

Comment: Try this. sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../')).

Comment: You don't want to add '/app', but the conatining folder to the path

Comment: Thank you!! that worked.

Comment: @serbia99 could you add that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `../app` is actually the *module* you are trying to import, appending the module directory to the path does not work. Instead you'd have to append the parent directory of the module, i.e.:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../'))
```